# Monitor suddenly only recognized as digital flat panel 640x480

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I daisy chained the following monitors with Display Port Cables: 
Dell U2414H,
Dell U2415

Everything worked fine till I came back from a presentation with my laptop and pluged the DP cable back in.

The first monitor is still recognized as before. But the second one gets recognized as "Digital Flat Panel" with a max resolution of 640x480.
The device manager looks like this:

[image]

Uninstalling the Flat Panel dind't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is inelegant, but it works:

1. Make sure Monitor #1 has DisplayPort 1.2 set as Enable.
   Monitor #2 should be set as Disable.
2. Open Device Manager.  Click Monitors.  Click View and Show Hidden Devices.
   Uninstall the Digital Flat Panel (640x480 60Hz) device.
   Also uninstall any hidden (greyed out) devices.
3. Disconnect Monitor 1 from computer.
4. Reboot computer
5. Unplug monitors and wait a few seconds
6. Plug monitors back in to power
7. Connect Monitor 1 to computer.

I've had this problem for years and have searched all over for an elegant solution.  To my knowledge, none exists.

Comment: Also try simply unplugging the power cable from the monitor, wait for windows to refresh the displays, then plug it back in, that usually fixes it for me. Still annoying, but at least it only takes seconds to do.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the 'Digital Flat Panel' and uninstall.

After it's uninstalled go to action and scan for hardware changes.

This will reinstall the driver for the monitor.

Comment: I tried to uninstall it as stated in my question. But when i scan for hardware changes it reinstalls the Digital Flat Panel instead of the driver for my monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Install Displaylink driver. After install, disconnect/connect monitor.

https://www.displaylink.com/downloads